# Refresh only content page in ASP.NET CORE Razor Pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

Please am a newbie in Razor pages. I need to integrate AdminLTE template into my Razor Page application which I have done successfully.

I placed the side bar menu with anchor tags that open specific pages, header bar and footer html code in the _Layout.chtml file and then I have the below div in the same _Layout.chtml to render the content pages

```
<div class="content-inner-all">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

This works alright but  when I click on any of the menu options it opens the content page alright but it refreshes the entire page together with the side bar.
What I want is to be able to click without refreshing the sidebar only the content page.
Please help me out
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to refresh or load content without refreshing the entire page, i'll advise you to integrate blazor server to your razor pages app.

Blazor allows you to split your admin template into different routable components and pages and the side bar and any other component that you doesn't need to be refresh won't be refreshed.

It might take a while getting used to but it would work best for your admin template.